# Sleep When I close the Lid - reverts to Do Nothing

Tags: sleep, power, lid

I set my Dell Latitude 7490 Laptop to *Sleep* when I close the lid:
[Choose what closing the lid does Sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t55wP.png)

However, some time later, as briefly as a few hours, without restarting, updating or any other settings changed, it reverts to *Do Nothing*, which has led to me running out of battery overnight and resultant unscheduled restarts. (To be clear, if I set to sleep then close the lid, and it sleeps, it stays sleeping. If it has reverted without my knowledge and *then* I close the lid, then it does nothing and the battery gets consumed.) I have also checked the Advanced Options, which seem to mimic whatever the dropdown power settings are:
[Advanced Power Settings Sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2yjZ.png)

I am using a work computer on Windows 10. I do not have admin privileges (but our IT are very responsive and cooperative). I cannot see any other power management programs that may be overriding this. Could it have been setup like this by an admin, leaving me powerless? They tell me they aren't pushing these types of settings out over the enterprise.
Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

> when I close the lid: ... and no updating or any other settings
> changed, it reverts to Do Nothing, which has led to me running out of
> battery overnight

Once suspended it with the lid closed, it should stay that way (assuming battery charge is OK) at least overnight.

Update BIOS, Power Driver, Network drivers and may sure in BIOS Settings that Wake on LAN (and Wake on anything else) are disabled.  Your IT department will need to do these updates for you.

Do a final restart and test.